# Is there an online resource that provides a current and comprehensive list of US Federal tax deductions and credits for individuals?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

There are lots of sites out there that have lists of common tax deductions/credits and several that list ones that people often forget to take. However, is there a good resource that provides a comprehensive list of Tax deductions/credits available to individual US Federal Income taxpayers?

Ideally I'd love to find a simplified list that includes every deduction/credit available with a short description and a link to the full version in the tax code.

This [site](http://financefreelancelife.com/2010/01/20/2009-tax-credit-and-deduction-list/) lists something close to what I am looking for, but it is only for 2009. Obviously something current to last year would be preferable.

Comment: If there's not, we can hopefully make the answer to this question the definitive, comprehensive list.

Comment: How about IRS.gov?

Comment: @stoj  - Good suggestion. Do you have a link to the IRS.gov page that lists all the available deductions/credits in a simplified list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not very easy. US tax code is very complex and has layers of conditions, exceptions, limitations, tweaks and twists, which may be very complex to navigate and easy to mess up. However, what you probably could do is take some tax preparation software - such as TurboTax, you can use it for free until you actually file and even file Federal for free, if I remember correctly. So, this software would have comprehensive itemized list of deductions, which you may browse freely or let it guide you through it. Each item usually is accompanies by explanations, what that one does, which forms you need to accompany it, what are conditions on it, etc.

Of course, it's not very "simplified", but it can be a start. You also could use the program to guide you and then decide if you want to pay to file or prepare your own return guided by the advice the program gives you.